# What is the filter attachment size of nikon AF-S 50 mm f/1.4G lens?

Tags: nikon

Please help me. I Need the information

Comment: What do Google search results say?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Apparently they don't say.

Answer (score 6):

It's written on the lens & the inside of the front lens cap.

[image]

⌀58 == 58mm

It's also the first hit if you Google for it, on [Nikon's own site](https://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/nikkor-lenses/auto-focus-lenses/fx/single-focal-length/af-s-nikkor-50mm-f-1-4g#tech_specs).

<sup>Not sure I'll ever make it as a product photographer, f18 & it's still not sharp right through. My excuse is all I did was plonk it on top of a flight case near a sunny window & went 'click' ;)</sup>